# Django allauth and ImportError

Tags: django, django-allauth

I've just done this introductions, and when I'm trying

```
./manage.py migrate
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/home/me0o/work/v_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/home/me0o/work/v_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 327, in execute
django.setup()
File "/home/me0o/work/v_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/home/me0o/work/v_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
File "/home/me0o/work/v_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 116, in create
mod = import_module(mod_path)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "/home/me0o/work/v_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/allauth/socialaccount/providers/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
from django.utils import importlib
ImportError: cannot import name importlib
```

I have Django 1.9.2
I have latest version of importlib
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`django.utils.importlib` was deprecated in Django 1.7 and removed in Django 1.9.

Since the error is occurring in allauth, you should upgrade django-allauth to the latest version. According to the [changelog](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/ChangeLog), version 0.24.0 should support Django 1.9.

Answer (score 0):

change your

```
from django.utils import importlib
```

to:

```
from importlib import import_module
```